# trying to understand .apply(undefined, arguments))

Tags: reactjs, debugging, call, apply, json-server

I've been developing an app in react. 
Just a Simple app, it has a feature where I check toggle/toggle state for items inside a list.

At utils.js I have

```
export const partial = (fn, ...args) => fn.bind(null, ...args)
const _pipe = (f, g) => (...args) => g(f(...args))
export const pipe = (...fns) => fns.reduce(_pipe)
```

but the there is a problem in App.js, when using the utils:

```
   const getToggledTodo = pipe(findById, toggleCompleted)
```

the helpers' imports seem fine:

```
import {pipe, partial} from  './lib/utils'

import {addTodo, generateId, findById, toggleCompleted, 
        updateTodo, removeTodo, filterTodos} from './lib/todoHelpers'
```

Still , the app complains

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined
```

doing console I get:

```
f2: function () {
        return g(f.apply(undefined, arguments));
      }
```

I looked at:

```
   at findById (todoHelpers.js:15)
    at utils.js:10

    at Object.executeOnChange (LinkedValueUtils.js:132)
```

and seems to me the undefined is coming from linkedValue file at last line:

```
  executeOnChange: function (inputProps, event) {
    if (inputProps.valueLink) {
      _assertValueLink(inputProps);
      return inputProps.valueLink.requestChange(event.target.value);
    } else if (inputProps.checkedLink) {
      _assertCheckedLink(inputProps);
      return inputProps.checkedLink.requestChange(event.target.checked);
    } else if (inputProps.onChange) {
      return inputProps.onChange.call(undefined, event);
    }
  }
};
```

Not sure how .apply and .call relate to each other here, and seems to me that I'm missing an argument somewhere.
The final objective is to update of state complete/not complete in the db, plus an message in the UI saying that in fact the item has been updated.

Fun fact: if I hard code some similar structured object in App.js and use it in memory to change state, the error does not show...  o_O.
It only appears when trying to connect to a 'db', which is still of course a mock. Don't know if its related but I think is worth mentioning. 
Using json-server to mock db objects.

So my question is: how to debug this error? Can someone help me understand a bit how apply and call relate to this error.

Any pointers in the right direction would be very helpful and much appreciated.